# Define two column in wpf (left column should take whole area if right column is collapsed or take half area if right column is visible)

Tags: wpf, xaml

Define two column in wpf,each column has a GridControl (left GridControl  should take whole area if right GridControl  is collapsed or take half area if right GridControl is visible)

I try to set ColumnDefinition (Width=auto or Width=*) but do not achieve the expectation

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```xml
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid Grid.Column="0">
        <Border BorderBrush="HotPink" BorderThickness="1">
            <TextBlock Text="Left Grid"/>
        </Border>
    </Grid>
    <Grid Grid.Column="1" Visibility="Collapsed">
        <Border BorderBrush="HotPink" BorderThickness="1">
            <TextBlock Text="Right Grid"/>
        </Border>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer,this way i have tried but do not achieve the expectation,My Problem has been solved by this link.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53316277/how-to-collapse-a-star-sized-grid-column-in-wpf